# http request to webhdfs, but empty reply from server

Tags: hadoop

I'm new in hadoop. I enabled the webhdfs and use the curl command to get a Home Directory.

curl -i  "http://172.16.18.50:9000/webhdfs/v1/?op=GETHOMEDIRECTORY"

But get the information : Empty reply from server.Here is the conf files:

core-site.xml  ----

```
<configuration>
   <property>
      <name>fs.default.name</name>
      <value>hdfs://webHDFS0:9000</value>
   </property>

   <property>
      <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
      <value>/home/eins/hadoop-1.0.2/tmp</value>
   </property>
</configuration>
```

hdfs-site.xml  ----

```
<configuration>
   <property>
      <name>dfs.replication</name>
      <value>2</value>
   </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.webhdfs.enabled</name>
        <value>enabled</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

Can anyone give some suggestions?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're trying to connect to the NameNode IPC socket (port 9000), rather than the web socket (which defaults to 50075). Try this instead:

```
http://172.16.18.50:50075/webhdfs/v1/?op=GETHOMEDIRECTORY
```

Also, your configuration in hdfs-site.xml needs to have `true` rather than `enabled` as its value:

hdfs-site.xml ----

```
<configuration>
   <property>
      <name>dfs.replication</name>
      <value>2</value>
   </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.webhdfs.enabled</name>
        <value>true</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

To confirm everything is working, look at the logs for your namenode, you should see something like:

```
2012-05-22 06:23:42,176 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer: dfs.webhdfs.enabled = true
2012-05-22 06:23:42,177 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer: Added filter 'SPNEGO' (class=org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.AuthFilter)
2012-05-22 06:23:42,179 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer: addJerseyResourcePackage: packageName=org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.web.resources;org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.resources, pathSpec=/webhdfs/v1/*
```

At the moment, i assume yours says:

```
2012-05-22 06:11:20,676 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer: dfs.webhdfs.enabled = false
```

Comment: I got "couldn't connect to host" when set port to 50075.
Then I tried the 50070, I got suck a strange html response : "...HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found...Error 404 NOT_FOUND ...... Problem accessing /webhdfs/v1/..."
If I removed the /webhdfs/vi, I can get a html respose : "...HTTP/1.1 200 OK..."

Comment: i updated my answer, looks like your hdfs-site config is wrong - use `true` rather then `enabled`

Comment: OGM... My classmate made a wrong configuration. That wastes our four days.
Then the last question: are there any limitations if the security is off(I didn't add filter and jerseyResourcePackage)?

Comment: I'm not sure about that - i'd read the webhdfs help page - http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r1.0.0/webhdfs.html#Authentication and if you have any further questions, post a new question rather than continue this thread

Comment: The default port for webhdfs, at least in the Hadoop 1.0.3 RPM, seems to be 50070 rather than 50075. But this can vary between systems.

Comment: I got "couldn't connect to host" when set port to 50075. Then I tried the 50070, I got suck a strange html response : "...HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found...Error 404 NOT_FOUND ...... Problem accessing /webhdfs/v1/..." If I removed the /webhdfs/vi, I can get a html respose : "...HTTP/1.1 200 OK..." I had exaxt same behavior.

Comment: @tarheels058 can you share the code please. I have the same issue

Comment: @tarheels058  I am facing the same problem please help